# Importing Local Project onto jBPM Docker Image

Tags: docker, jbpm

I am attempting to import a local git repository into a jBPM Docker Image (jboss/jbpm-server-full). I had successfully imported a local repository using just the jBPM Server Final, without Docker, using git commands and then importing via file:///{path to project}.

I am wondering if it is possible to use the same importing process for the jBPM Docker Image. I have tried following the same process multiple times, yet cannot find any success.

Is it possible to import a local repository on the jBPM Docker Image, or is this feature not included? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter if you do it from a Docker container. It should work the same.

If you want to import it from a local file storage in the container, then you have to copy it inside, with docker cp my_repo.git.tgz container_name:/tmp, then extract it from inside and in import in jbpm-console use file:/tmp/my_repo.git
Or you can add a volume to the docker and set the .git folder there, and then locate it the same with a file:/var/lib/volume_name/additional_path/my_repo.git

You can also import it from a web via import and then http_address/my_repo.git , example via repo in github